# Inverse of a particular Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I have the following matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
b & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
a & b & a & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & a & b & a & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & a & b & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & a & b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & b & a\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & b
\end{pmatrix}$$

That can be written as $A=T+u_{1}v_{1}^{T}+u_{2}v_{2}^{T}$, where T is tridiagonal. I have to compute the inverse of this matrix in terms of $T^{-1}$. I had thought that I could extend the [Sherman-Morris formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), but the procedure for obtaining it cannot be applied to this case. In the statement of the problem there is a hint. It says that it is useful writting $A=L(\mathbb{I}+stuff)U$ [sic]. Where L (U) is a lower (upper) triangular matrix. I have thought that those LU could be the LU factorization of A, but when U compute $L^{-1}(u_{1}v_{1}^{T}+u_{2}v_{2}^{T})U^{-1}$ the stuff term becomes a singular matrix. Do you have any tip to solve this problem?.

Comment: Can you find the $LU$-decomposition of $T$? Also, have you tried using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)?

Comment: Potentially helpful point: note that $T$ can conveniently [be diagonalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). In particular, we have $T = UDU^T$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix $D = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ with 
$$
\lambda_k = a + 2b\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right)
$$
and $U$ is the matrix whose $k$th column is given by
$$
v_k = \left( \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1} \right), 
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1} \right),\dots ,\sin\left(\frac{n \pi k}{n+1} \right)\right), \quad k = 1,\dots, n.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, I have found the LU decomposition of T. Thank you for suggesting the Woodbury matrix identity, it would solve my problem except for the fact that $L^{-1}(u_{1}v_{1}^{T}+u_{2}v_{2}^{T})U^{-1}$ and $u_{1}v_{1}^{T}+u_{2}v_{2}^{T}$ are singular.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe that this prevents you from using the Woodbury matrix identity

Comment: @BenGrossmann well, in the wikipedia article the identity reads $$\left(A + UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$$ But in my case $C^{-1}$ does not exist

Comment: Right, so there is no requirement that the matrix $UCV$ should be invertible

Answer (score 1):

You have reduced the problem to that of finding the inverse of $I + L^{-1}(u_1v_1^T + u_2v_2^T)U^{-1}$. With that in mind, apply the Woodbury matrix identity to compute $(I + PQR)^{-1}$, where
$$
P = \pmatrix{L^{-1}u_1 & L^{-1}u_2}, \quad Q =  I_{2 \times 2}, \quad R =  \pmatrix{v_1^TU^{-1}\\v_2^TU^{-1}}.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I am still trying to find a way to express the inverse matrix in terms of $T^{-1}$ using just my knowledge in LU decomposition